# Running Mongock on only one database in multidatabase Spring project

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongock

I have quite large legacy multi module Java Spring boot project which connects to one MySql database and two Mongo databases (lets say `codebook` and `report`).
I'm trying to setup Mongock to be able to do Mongo database migrations. I need it on only one Mongodb database (`report`).
I added Mongock dependencies and configuration class (`MongockApplicationRunner`, `MongoTransactionManager`) to `report` database.
When I run the application it gives me exception: *Scan package for changeLogs is not set: use appropriate setter* (exception from `RunnerBuilderBase` class).
I debugged it and found that Mongock is trying to set configuration for `codebook` database.
I created another Mongock configuration, this time for `codebook` database. Run the application. Mongock loads my new configuration for `codebook`, but then tries to set another configuration for `codebook` database which failes because of `config.getChangeLogsScanPackage().isEmpty()`.
It seems that Mongock is always setting some default configuration on `codebook` database.
When I debug it Mongock loads first `codebook` configuration from my `mongockApplicationRunner` (line `.buildApplicationRunner();`). The second `codebook` configuration comes from `MongockContextBase.applicationRunner` and that configuration has empty `MongockSpringConfiguration.migrationScanPackage`.
Why is this *default* configuration appearing and how to stop it from loading?
My Spring boot is `2.2.13.RELEASE` and Mongock is `5.0.24`.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the "/" in @Qualifier(value = "reportMongoTemplate"/"codeBookMongoTemplate")?

Comment: That is just an example how would other qualifier look like. First would be named "reportMongock", second "codeBookMongock". Same for parameters: MongoTemplate for first mongockApplicationRunner runner would have qualifier "reportMongoTemplate" and for second runner MongoTemplate would be "codeBookMongoTemplate".

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of wasted time I found that besides Mongock configuration on `report` database I was also doing autoconfiguration (`@EnableMongock`).
I had annotation `@EnableMongock` on my *MongockConfig* class. Since `codebook` mongo template had `@Primary` annotation autocofiguration was loading that database and there were no properties to set changelog directory inside `application.properties` so *ChangeLogsScanPackages* were empty.
Simple solution, I just removed `@EnableMongock` annotation and it started working.
Don't mix autoconfiguration (`@EnableMongock`) with creating `mongockApplicationRunner` and `transactionManager` or you will end up with problem like me.

Comment: We were trying to reproduce without success. Our mistake was that we assumed you weren't annotating your app with `@EnableMongock`. This annotation is to delegate the work of building the Mongock runner to Mongock itself. As you were doing that job, that annotation was only not needed, was actually conflicting

Comment: Thanks for support @MongockTeam. Yeah, you have to start from assumption that people (me) won't do the most obvious things. :(

Answer (score 0):

When using **@EnableMongock** within your spring boot application,  you must define the configuration to let Mongock scan the migrations as below:

```
mongock:
  migration-scan-package:
    - com.ma.project.migrations
```

In case you want to keep the Mongock without running migrations, you can configure it to be disabled as below:

```
mongock:
  enabled: off
```